# WD External HDD is RAW and won't to save any things?

Tags: hard-drive

I have WD elements 2tb. Won't to save any things. And I have tried to erase or format it but without success. Took long time more than 24 hours but nothing happens the progress stuck on 0%

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IAar.png)

How can I test or check it if dead or can fix it ?!!

P.S: I am using ubunut 22.04

Comment: I had a similar problem. I put Linux on a USB. Turned the machine off and only left the problem drive. Booted with the USB and installed linux on the bad drive, it now works like a dream. I have had problems with format before so that is why only one drive was connected. This is not a solution but for me it was a work around.

Comment: I have try also what you advice but without success, more than 18 hours, and the installation was not stopped, the process on formatting the hard disk ext4.

Comment: At this point take advantage of the drive warranty if it still has one, otherwise it will become a good paper weight.